# Pass class object from ruby to liquid (via Jekyll)

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

UPDATE FOR CLARIFICATION.

I deleted the original question because it was confusing. Maybe this one is better?

I currently have something like this (simplified for brevity):

```
module Jekyll
    module TOCGenerator
        def toc(html)
            ...via nokogiri, get all <h3> tags, make table of contents entry
            for each. 
        end
        def contentWithTocAnchorLinks(html)
            ...make "back to top" anchor links under each <h3> tag that will
            take the user back up to the table of contents 
        end
    end
end
```

Then in the template:

```
<section>{{ content | toc }}</section>
<section>{{ content | contentWithTocAnchorLinks }} </section>
```

This works fine, but it seems sloppy. I've also tried stuffing both `toc` and `contentWithAnchorLinks` into an array and then doing something like `{{ content | tocArray | first }}` which also worked, but not very well (in some cases there is no table of contents and it was confusing). Anyway, what I would like to be able to do is something like this:

```
{% capture toc_content %}{{ content | toc_generate }}{% endcapture %}
<section> {{ toc_content.toc }} </section>
<section> {{ toc_content.content }}</section>
```

Jekyll does this all the time, as in `{{ page.title }}` but I'm not clear on how to replicate it. I only assume that a Ruby class is involved somewhere.

Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to parse a content, get some customers infos from it, and render a table of content.

From the Information Architecture point of view, you are supposed to store your customer datas in an atomic manner. For this, Jekyll offers you [data files](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/) and [collections](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) that can be very helpful in your case.

If you need to make some basic transformations on your "objects" you can use [liquid](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters) or [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#filters) filters.

Comment: I updated my question. Maybe it make more sense now?